# Flot line Chart without date/time

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Could you please anyone help me, i trying to create flot line chart, comparision two values. 
is it possible create without time?. i have searched everywhere, i unable to find line chart without date/time.

```
var options = {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%d/%m",
                tickSize: [1, "day"]
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 0
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
            selection: {
                mode: "x"
            }

        };
```

Instead of time or date, i need to show my own data like 'john', 'amit','gourav' in x axis.

Please help me.

Comment: i don't think you can do this directly in flot. you could use tooltips or try using highcharts instead

Comment: http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-flot/tooltip-line-chart.html

Comment: yes. it seems to be like that only. anyway thank you Rachel.

Comment: What do you mean by 'comparison two values'?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `category mode` for that (category plugin: [example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html), [example code](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/examples/categories/index.html)).

Basic code (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFq3K/1/) for the result):

```
var data = [ ['john', 13], ['amit', 17], ['gourav', 9] ];

$.plot('#div', [ data ], {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: 'categories'
    }
});
```

Comment: the problem is, i want to make comparison chart in flot line. That's why i could not make it.

Comment: @KanagarajVadivel, if by comparison, you mean more than one series, just add another series: http://jsfiddle.net/uFq3K/2/